# $_POST variables not available on pages without HTML headers

Tags: php, post, http-headers

I used to be able to post variables to pure PHP pages, but it seems to have been broken by a server setting change with our web host, because this used to work just fine. Basically, I've set up a form to retrieve and allow the user to download a file from a secure location outside of the public folder on the server (only to authorized users). It works like this:

**request_file.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Request File</title>
</head>

<body>

<form name="request_file" method="post" action="retrieve_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="filename" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**retrieve_file.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Vary: User-Agent");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_POST['filename']);

readfile( "../../".$_SESSION['userid']."/".$_POST['filename'] );

?>
```

However, if I replace the retrieve_file.php code with simply this:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $_POST );
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

It will print out an empty array, every time. However, if I put HTML headers on retrieve_file.php, it works just fine. However, for exporting a file, this won't really work since the headers have to be sent out AFTER the page gets its post variables.

Any ideas how to work around this? Please don't berate me for pulling files this way, it actually works well for our very specific application.

Thanks!

**Additional Information**

PHP Version: 5.4

Comment: I prefer `xsendfile` for stuff like this (and do _validate_ `$_POST['filename']`, or they can download _any_ file the webserver has access to with a little bit of guessing & applying `../` there). The problem itself puzzles me. Are you saying the if you add a few `header()` calls in front of it, that `$_POST` then magically is filled? That would be _very weird_. If you inspect the `$_SERVER` array, are you actually receiving a `POST` request? And if you look into the network history of your browser, there is no redirect anywhere?

Comment: BTW: _"headers have to be sent out AFTER the page gets its post variables"_ is not striclty true: PHP will have received them or not, you can do everything you want without damaging your original input (aside from manually emptying `$_POST` of course).

Comment: Some other things to try: check `variables_order`, remove the `enctype` (you don't need that if you don't _upload_ files), inspect what you can from the `$_SERVER` array.

Comment: @jbalyo Your code for me works great. Check again your code/server/apache/php. Obs.: if you can, insert a screenshot of the error, and informations about your apache/php version, etc. And... see your error.log/access.log

Comment: @Wrikken you're a genius. Thanks so much. When you mentioned redirects, I remembered some recent changes that I'd forgotten about. We had recently installed SSL on the site, and what was happening is the form was under http:// and it was posting to the file with a relative link, but the .htaccess file was quietly forwarding it to https:// ... I added an exception for the file in .htaccess forwarding and everything is working again. Thanks so much!

Comment: Aight, nice to know _one_ of my zillion guesses hit the mark ;)

Comment: BTW: that would mean your session-cookies go out over plain HTTP on that request_form. Which means anyone can steal the contents of the session cookie. Don't expect much in protection from being logged in or not, unless you force sessions to be HTTPS-only.

Comment: I understand. I can also do the reverse, though. I can force both to go out over HTTPS, as long as both pages are the same. The forward itself was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access with the $_FILES variable, like this:

$_FILES["file"]["filename"]

Check more at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: That would be true if I were attempting to upload a file from the form. However, this is something else. The file already exists on the server in a folder. This form allows a user to retrieve and download that file FROM the server. The only thing I'm posting here is actually the filename itself, from a standard text input.

Comment: Jaha! Ok, i got it now. Do you really need the multipart encoding type? If not, then you can remove it from there and access using the $_POST strategy.